# WebClient giving MediaType not supported Exception when using class with custom getter setter as RequestBody

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, jackson2, spring-webclient

I have class all classes in my spring Webflux Application which has getter/setters without get and set prefix and setter return this. Hence i have also defined my custom Jackson Configuration for that which works fine with all my controllers successfully for serialising deserialising.

My Jackson Config

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration implements Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {

  @Override
  public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
    jacksonObjectMapperBuilder
      .serializationInclusion(NON_NULL)
      .failOnUnknownProperties(false)
      .visibility(FIELD, ANY)
      .modulesToInstall(new ParameterNamesModule(PROPERTIES));
  }
}
```

My Request Class

```
@Accessors(chain = true, fluent = true)
@Getter
@Setter // from project Lombok
public class Test {
  private String a;
  private List<String> b;
}
```

Now if I make request using webclient like below

```
  public Mono<Void> postRequest(String a, List<String> b) {
    Webclient webclient = Webclient.create();
    return webClient.post()
      .uri("some_url")
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .bodyValue(new Test().a(a).b(b))
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(Void.class);
  }
```

I get an exception like below

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType=<Classpath>
```

but instead if i pass a Map like below, it works.

```
  public Mono<Void> postRequest(String a, List<String> b) {
    Webclient webclient = Webclient.create();
    return webClient.post()
      .uri(format("some_url")
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .bodyValue(new HashMap<String,Object>(){{put("a",a);put("b",b);}})
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(Void.class);
  }
```

I have tried removing @Accessor annotation and creating the getter setter myself but still it doesn't works.

I think the exception is occurring due to some deserialisation issue. I am not sure though. Jackson works fine with all my controllers in the application.

How can i make the first case work where i can provide a class as body instead of a Map?

Comment: try removing the `@Accessors` annotation

Comment: @ThomasAndoIf   <@ Accessors> Annotation creates getter and setters without get and set prefix and the setters which return this. Even if i remove them and write similar getter setters which they create it still errors out. Issue is not with that.

Comment: I am fully aware of what it does thank you, i also know how jackson works so i was trying process of elimination. Since you havn’t written all things you have tried im not going to spend time guessing. If you expect help write out ALL things you have tried so others don’t have to spend time guessing. Good luck.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Sorry sir, my bad, i should have mentioned. My intention wasn't to annoy anyone, i was just trying to clarify. But yeah it is my mistake. Have updated the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating Webclient like below solved my issue.

```
  public WebClient webClient() {
    WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder();
    builder.exchangeStrategies(EXCHANGE_STRATEGIES)
      .defaultHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    return builder.build();
  }

  public static final ObjectMapper GSON_LIKE_OM = new ObjectMapper()
    .setSerializationInclusion(NON_NULL)
    .setVisibility(FIELD, ANY)
    .configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule(PROPERTIES));

  public static final ExchangeStrategies EXCHANGE_STRATEGIES = ExchangeStrategies
    .builder()
    .codecs(clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer -> {
      clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(GSON_LIKE_OM, APPLICATION_JSON));
      clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(GSON_LIKE_OM, APPLICATION_JSON));
    }).build();
```